# Registering generic type in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Currently I have an installer with the following code:

```
container.Register(Component.For<EntityListResolver<Unit>>()
         .ImplementedBy<EntityListResolver<Unit>>());
container.Register(Component.For<EntityResolver<Unit>>()
         .ImplementedBy<EntityResolver<Unit>>());
```

I would like to change this registration so that it will automatically resolve for any type that I send in instead of `Unit`

How do I change my registration to achieve this?

Comment: Can you use generics, or is the type you want to resolve not known until runtime?

Comment: it can definately be generic, all of base type `BaseEntity`

Answer (score 5):

You can use open generics eg.:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(EntityListResolver<>))()
         .ImplementedBy(typeof(EntityListResolver<>))());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your types at compile time, you can do the registration in a generic function:

```
void Register<T>()
{
    container.Register(Component.For<EntityListResolver<T>>()
             .ImplementedBy<EntityListResolver<T>>());
    container.Register(Component.For<EntityResolver<T>>()
             .ImplementedBy<EntityResolver<T>>());
}
```

Then simply call `Register<Unit>();` or whatever type you need.

Comment: And if you don't know the type at compile time?

Comment: @Kurren: You can use Reflection to get a reference to `Register<T>` specialized to whatever type you want.